# After clearing float, text in next div is pushed to the left

Tags: css, html, css-float

I am using CSS to float a div next to another one. This div only appears if the user is looking at their own "business." When I don't clear anything, a large space appears between these divs and the next one. When I do clear the float, the text in the next div is pushed to the left. I think I am misunderstanding something about how to use the float and clear. I'm not very good with CSS.

How can I remove the space without destroying the "fs" div?

Here are pictures to show what is happening:

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Here's the CSS and HTML code:

```
div.stuff {
    border-bottom:dotted 1px;
    border-left:dotted 1px;
    border-right:dotted 1px;
    border-top:dotted 1px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    width:35%;
    height:65px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
div.container {
    border-bottom:dotted 1px;
    border-left:dotted 1px;
    border-right:dotted 1px;
    border-top:dotted 1px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    position:relative;
    height:65px;
    width:45%;
    top:-97px;
    right:10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
div.fs {
    border-style:double;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    margin-left:20%;
    width:60%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

<div class=stuff>
    <img src=/economy/images/cash.png> Cash on Hand: 10,245<br>
    <img src=/economy/images/worker.png> Workers Employed: 6<br>
    <img src=/economy/images/machine.png> Machines Leased: 4
</div>
<div class=container>
    <a href="/economy.php?section=business&do=contribute">Click Here to Manage Cash on Hand.</a><br>
    <a href="/economy.php?section=business&do=moderate">Click Here to Manage this Business.</a><br>
    <a href="/economy.php?section=business&do=info&action=disband&id=7">Click Here to Disband this Business.</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class=fs><a href=/economy.php?section=fs&id=7>Historical Financial Statements</a></div>
```

Comment: You really should care about CSS Shorthands. So this: `border-bottom:dotted 1px; border-left:dotted 1px; border-right:dotted 1px; border-top:dotted 1px;` becomes this `border: 1px dotted;` Much cleaner imho :) @see http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Comment: Thanks, I was trying border: dotted 1px; and it didn't work, so I assumed I had to do it the long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to float your left hand `div`, and use `clear:both` on the `div` at the bottom. I've made some changes in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37WFy/).

Comment: This worked great. I had to add a top:10px; to the container div to position it correctly, but otherwise there were no issues. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can away the `top` completely and give it the same padding and margin as the `div` on the left.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this:

```
div.container {
   border-bottom:dotted 1px;
   border-left:dotted 1px;
   border-right:dotted 1px;
   border-top:dotted 1px;
   padding:10px;
   padding-left:25px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   position:relative;
   height:65px;
   width:45%;
   /*top:-97px;*/
   margin-top:-97;
   right:10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   float:right;
   /*clear:right;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would float your `div.stuff` to the left and your `div.container` to the right and just use `clear: both` on the `div.fs` element. I made a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rG4Bw/) to illustrate this. In this fiddle I added a wrapper class for clarity where I set a `min-width` to prevent that the right div floats down one line when the browser window is resized. Try it out!

Here's the CSS:

```
div.stuff {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    width:35%;
    height:65px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
}
div.container {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    position:relative;
    height:65px;
    width:45%;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:right;
}
div.fs {
    clear: both;
    border-style:double;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    margin-left:20%;
    width:60%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}​
```